# What is meant by an exploratory interview

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

Last week I had an interview with a technical company with all the rounds happening on the same day. The HR asked me for my documents and then today they said that they want to share an exploratory call with the CTO of the company.

What will this interview entail and where do I stand my chances in getting an offer with the company.

Comment: The purpose of an initial interview (typically called a phone screen) would be a good question for this site, but that's not what you're asking about as you already had a previous interview. What a particular step in a company's hiring process involves and what it's for is something only that company's recruiters can answer (VTC company-specific). It's likely that the CTO just wants to have an informal chat to check for culture fit and knowledge but it could be much more or much less. **Ask your hiring contact.**

Comment: The chance you'll get an offer are pretty good, but one can't really be sure. For one thing, it really depends on the company itself. And for that, I'd check a site like glassdoor to see if that's usually the way they interview and make job offers.

Comment: Usually, at the end of these types of phone calls with HR, they'll ask if you have any questions. Ask for clarification. You're having a call with the CTO, you don't want any surprises. You're not in HR, so you shouldn't be expected to know their jargon.

Comment: You may want to edit this question and remove the part about the chances of an offer; we can't predict that. Your question "What is an exploratory interview?" is on topic if it is a common term used by HR.

Comment: And it's silly to try to close this for "Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department."  It's not company-specific and used broadly in the HR industry.

Comment: It sounds like you are going to do a phone screen.  They are usually short get to know you conversations to determine if you should come in for an onsite interview.

Comment: @dyeje he said he already had an initial interview "with all the rounds happening on the same day" so this is definitely not a phone screen.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep true, but it seems to be like he is being screened by a new party.  Perhaps they are considering him for a different position.

Comment: @dyeje I can see that.  "You're not a good fit for what we initially interviewed you for but you seem to have good skills. Maybe you can be of use elsewhere in the firm"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Human resources isn't my field, but typically I think of an "exploratory interview" as an initial, (relatively) brief interview to get an idea of whether the organization wants to have you in for a longer interview. My most recent interview was preceded by an exploratory interview with a single manager (over lunch) who wanted to get an idea of whether it was worth having me in to meet with her full team.

However, you've indicated that you've already been through some interviewing with this company, so obviously the above isn't what is meant by "exploratory interview" here. Since they are asking you to have this exploratory interview with the CTO, it is reasonable to assume that you were found acceptable during the first interviews. Admittedly, the following is speculation, as this company could do things differently. However, based on similar experiences I have had, I expect the CTO has veto power over hiring in this department and wants to meet with prospective hires. If you are found acceptable, it's likely you'll receive an offer.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, it's a "conversation" as opposed to a job interview. It's also called "informational".  In an exploratory interview, they're not necessarily going to offer you a job. This doesn't mean that they're not valuable to you. They're great opportunities to share your passion and your knowledge with the CTO as well as explore what the company does.

It is entirely possible you could get an offer at some point, possibly even a referral to a colleague at another company. What makes this so different from a typical job interview is that the lack of an offer afterward doesn't mean necessarily that you did anything wrong or weren't a good fit.  It's not a pass/fail situation.

From [Houston Chronicle](http://chameleonresumes.com/2015/04/24/exploratory-interviews-land-and-make-them-work-for-you/)

> An exploratory interview is intended to give interviewees in-depth information about a particular profession or industry. Someone already working in the profession can give insight as to what the job is really like, what skills are necessary to succeed and how best to secure relevant experience. For interviewees new to the professional world, informational interviews are one way to gain experience doing interviews and meeting with colleagues in the professional world.

Comment: I've been through one. I was referred by a classmate, and although it was like a typical interview, it was more friendly and casual. The CTO met me briefly and then the VP spoke with me for an hour. We spoke of the challenges the company is facing, how I'd tackle them, what my likes were (as in, what career path I'd have chosen if I had a choice). He evaluated my intelligence and my inclination for taking up a job at the company. He also proposed introducing me to his other colleagues if I was interested.

Comment: @JohnDavid I've never personally had one.  Did you come out of it glad that you did it or did you see it as ultimately a waste of time?

Comment: Wasn't a waste of time. The 'interviewer' was sensible, focused and cordial. In the beginning itself he reminded me that it was not a typical interview, but more of discussion. The process was good because it made me think about what I really wanted to do and whether I'd actually wanted to join the company. Turned out I didn't, because the technologies I wanted to work on were completely different. Anyway, I got another job offer at another company later that day (standard interview), so didn't look back.

Comment: I hope they bought you food while on your date